# Position button on bottom of screen relative to its image

Tags: html, css, button, position

I'm tearing my hair out trying to understand why I can't seem to position my button relative to its image BUT on the bottom portion of the screen. I have tried reading the other questions however couldn't think of a solution from the previous responses. Maybe my situation different?

Essentially, I'm trying to position the button underneath the image  while keeping it (button) centered and keep it responsive. I'm a long time reader first time question-asker. Any input leading to solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe my divs are off?

```css
.randomImage {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  top: 20%;
}
.btnGroup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}
#buttonOne {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="blackOverLay">

  <div class="imageContainer">
    <div class="imageHold">
      <image class="randomImage" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9dq_0kM7kPFwPJAzHSFNRThXKHmD1ryYDf78YrDNJX7IiExM3sA">
        </img>
        <div class="btnGroup">
          <button id="buttonOne" onclick="closeThis()">CLOSE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `<image ...>
        </img>` ?? Not really valid HTML Also if you fix the image container, you can insert the button in the fixed container

Comment: Thank you mplungjan - you're right, can't believe I wrote that. Fixed. Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you, this is that u want.

```css
.randomImage {
position: absolute;

right: 0;
left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;

height: auto;
width: auto;
}

.btnGroup {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 20px;
color: red;
}

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#buttonOne {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0
 }
```

```html
<div class="blackOverLay">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="imageHold">
            <img class="randomImage" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9dq_0kM7kPFwPJAzHSFNRThXKHmD1ryYDf78YrDNJX7IiExM3sA" />
            <div class="btnGroup">
                <button id="buttonOne" onclick="closeThis()">CLOSE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, yes! - Thank you! i set the 'bottom' to % though for responsiveness. And it seems to be doing the trick. Much appreciated. It seems I was missing the  css for imageContainer. Live'n'learn / *embarassment* at the same time. =D